# How can I get my grid column to stay the same size (height and width) when resizing viewports?

Tags: html, css

I have a container that will have a picture of the day. When changing viewport sizes (mobile screen size) the container gets squashed so much that the image is not readable.. How can I get the containers in my grid system to stay the exact same size relative to the viewport? Thank you!!

```css
html,
body,
form,
main {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #232A35;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.mainheader {
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 100%;
}

.iotd {
  grid-area: iotd;
}

.banner {
  grid-area: banner;
}

.solutions {
  grid-area: solutions;
}

.services {
  grid-area: services;
}

.tud {
  grid-area: tud;
}

.resources {
  grid-area: resources;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'iotd banner banner banner banner banner' 'iotd solutions services resources tud tud';
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .grid-container>div {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid mainheader">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="iotd col">IOTD</div>
      <div class="banner col">Banner</div>
      <div class="solutions col">Solutions</div>
      <div class="services col">Services</div>
      <div class="tud col">The Unrecovery Difference</div>
      <div class="resources col">Resources</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The container that will hold the image is labeled as "IOTD"
Any help is appreciated

Comment: for such a wide grid, isn't it better to change the layout on mobile for better visibility ? and why not use bootstrap, does it have to be manual ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The grid cells _are_ the same size relative to the viewport. Please revise to be more specific. Also, images should generally not contain text. It's bad practice from a usability and accessibility standpoint, as you've seen. If possible, lay text _over_ your image.

Comment: Can you please clarify what the layout should look like on smaller screens. "exact same size relative to the viewport" sounds self contradictory. If you just want the IOTD container to have a minimum width, you can do just that, apply a `min-width' to it.

Answer (score 0):

resolved the issue by changing the image size rather than the container size when the viewport reaches 900px. I also change the font size to a smaller size which in turn makes all of the containers smaller

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to include a `grid-template-columns` rule to specify how you want the horizontal space apportioned, this can include a minimum absolute (px) width for the first column with the option of allowing it to grow when more space is available using `minmax`.

For example, I've added the following rule to your css:

```
grid-template-columns: minmax(150px, 1fr)  repeat(5, 1fr);
```

This divides the grid into 6 columns to be consistent with your area template (which remains in operation) but makes the first column at least 150px wide with the option of expanding with the other columns when extra width is available. The remaining five columns are allocated 1/5 of the available space by specifying 5 `1fr` fractions.

Here's the rule added to your example:

```css
html,
body,
form,
main {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #232A35;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.mainheader {
  border: 1px red solid;
  width: 100%;
}

.iotd {
  grid-area: iotd;
}

.banner {
  grid-area: banner;
}

.solutions {
  grid-area: solutions;
}

.services {
  grid-area: services;
}

.tud {
  grid-area: tud;
}

.resources {
  grid-area: resources;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'iotd banner banner banner banner banner' 'iotd solutions services resources tud tud';
  grid-template-columns: minmax(150px, 1fr)  repeat(5, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .grid-container>div {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid mainheader">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="iotd col">IOTD</div>
      <div class="banner col">Banner</div>
      <div class="solutions col">Solutions</div>
      <div class="services col">Services</div>
      <div class="tud col">The Unrecovery Difference</div>
      <div class="resources col">Resources</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Grid_Template_Areas has examples where `grid-template-areas` are combined with `grid-template-columns` (it also has some ideas on using media queries to suit different view ports).

Comment: Wow, I thought I had figured out a solution but this is wayyyy better! Thank you so much I had no idea about the minmax feature of the grid-template-columns. This helped me so much. Thank you!